# Working out averages for goals scored per football game

Tags: probability, average, percentages

If for example I had a sample set of 11 football games.  Of those 11 games, there were a total of 8 goals.  So I can work out the average goals per game by

```
goals / games
```

0.727272727272727

However, for those 8 goals, they were only scored in 5 of the games.  What calculation do I need to use to incorporate the fact that these goals were only scored in 5 of the games.

Can I work out the probability/percentage of a goal like 5/11 (eg only 5 of the games out of the 11 a goal was scored)

0.454545454545455 eg 45.45% ?

Comment: What are you asking?  If $8$ goals were scored over $5$ games, then there were $\frac 85$ goals scored in each of those $5$ games, on average. Of course, there were only $\frac 8{11}$ goals scored, on average, over the full $11$ games.  But I expect you are asking something else.

Comment: Can I work out the chance as a percentage of a goal being scored, if only 5 of the 11 games had a goal ?

Comment: Well, no.  As far as the data goes all $8$ goals could have been scored in $1$ game, or you might have a goal in each of the $5$ games, or anything in between. Average calculations assume uniformity.  In this case, uniformity is not even a physical possibility (as $\frac 85$ is not an integer).

Comment: Tommassiov, are you asking how to predict the likelihood of at least one goal being scored in a certain future soccer game, based on what was observed in those 11 games?

Comment: I can work out average goals per game as per above, but what does games scored in / total games give me ? Is that the likelihood?

Comment: @lulu I've updated my question with further details..

Comment: Well, you have $11$ observation with $5$ "successes" so you might guess that a random observation has a $\frac 5{11}$ of being a success.  But the evidence is pretty weak.  If, say, a sceptic asserted that it was a coin toss (probability $\frac 12$) a quick calculation shows that you'd have better than a $22\%$ chance of scoring in exactly $5$ of $11$ games.  So...I really don't think you can conclude much.

Comment: to be clear:  the (big) problem is the small data list.  In principle, using the number of successes over a block of trials gives the maximum likelihood estimation for the probability of success (assuming you have a Bernouilli process).  But with so few observations it really could be significantly off.  Also, the number of goals (in goal scoring games) seems too high.  Makes me think the process is not Bernouilli...usually with sports one assumes that team $A's$ chances vary with their opponent.  Play a weak opponent, you'll get multiple goals.  Play a strong one, you won't score.

Comment: I do have a much bigger set of data these 11 games were for the question. Also how do you arrive at a quick calculation with better than 22% chance ?